# Vim and Clojure, can I use Slimv or VimClojure with ritz or another REPL?

Tags: vim, clojure, slimv, vimclojure

I can successfully configure both `Slimv` and `VimClojure` but I wonder if I can set any of those to work with any `swank server` (`ritz` for example).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory Slimv can connect to any swank server, but there is no autodetection currently for ritz-swank. So if you want to use ritz, then you need to start the swank server manually, or define the shell command for Slimv that starts the swank server, e.g. by adding a similar line to your .vimrc (assuming you run ritz on Linux via Leiningen):

`let g:slimv_swank_clojure = '! xterm -e lein ritz 4005 &'`

Recent versions of ritz-swank had some protocol changes, so I suggest that you get the most recent Slimv version from the [repository](https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv), which adds a new function 'Break on Exception'.

You can of course use swank-clojure as well via `lein swank`, and Slimv can autodetect and run it for you.

I'm the author of Slimv, I plan to add more support for ritz, as swank-clojure seems to be abandoned now. If you have any problems with Slimv, please feel free to contact me.

EDIT: I have now added a simple autodetection for ritz-swank: if Slimv finds `~/.lein/plugins/lein-ritz*.jar` then it is able to start ritz-swank by pressing `,c`.

Comment: Hey @Tamas - couple questions: 1. does auto-detection work with lein2? 2. Have you considered adding nrepl support to slimv? Thanks.

Comment: 1.) No, slimv only checks for the presence of `lein`, but if you named lein2 to lein (as I think some tutorials suggest) then slimv will find it. Please drop me a mail if you want a more sophisticated solution.  2.) I must admit that I don't really know nrepl. Slimv targets to be a 'Slime for Vim', so the aim is to provide the same functionality as Slime does for Emacs. Therefore I did not plan to add nrepl support, rather the swank server itself may run on a remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an nREPL option as well:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-foreplay

The creator of VimClojure recommended using that for nREPL for the time being - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vimclojure/B-UU8qctd5A/nHXJiGMkXJsJ

Answer (score 0):

VimClojure does not use swank as backend, so you can't use it with a swank server.

Comment: I meant to use slimv to connect to swank, and vimclojure for the rest of it. but thanks anyway!

Comment: @ssedano Well, that should work. Highlighting and basic completion is mostly independent from the backend. Just do a `let vimclojure#WantNailgun = 0` in your `.vimrc` and you should be set from the VimClojure point of view.

Comment: That's what I did, sorry if the question didn't make it clear. Thanks!